# Conventional usage of "this" in Java class to refer to an instance variable

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions, instance-variables

Is the following usage of "this" to refer to an instance variable in the current class acceptable? In PHP this is how you would have to do it, but I noticed in Java you can just call the variable by name directly.

I personally find "this.variable" to be more understandable but I don't want to develop bad coding habits if that isn't normal.

Thanks!

```
public class MyClass {  

    /**
     * Private variable
     */
    private int myInt;

    /**
     * Setter method
     */
    public void setMyInt(int value) {
        this.myInt = value;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Acceptability depends strictly on your style guidelines because exactly the same code is generated either way. Some require it, others disallow it, and most probably don't care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like people have been saying, its not required, but it is acceptable.

That being said it is necessary if you're doing something like this:

```
private int value;

public void setValue(int value) {
     this.value = value;
}
```

Which differentiates between the class variable and the parameter with the same name. I find myself using this pattern in almost every setter I make, and is about the only time I use the 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly acceptable practice in Java, although it's not required (as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

I'd write your code like this:

```
public class MyClass {

  private int myInt;

  public void setMyInt(int myInt) {
    this.myInt = myInt;
  }
}
```

The difference to yours is (beside having removed useless Javadoc) that in my code the parameter has the same name as the member variable. Other users prefer to give the member variable a different name than the parameter, but we prefer to prefix the member variables *where necessary* with `this.` because of visual balance. In over 10 years of Java coding using this standard we never had a bug which was caused by using the wrong variable.

Comment: I guess I fall in the camp of preferring my params to have a different name since it helps me understand what I am setting with. Sorry for the excess docs.

Comment: How do you name the parameters if a method have multiple ones? `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, ...? The alternative is to prefix (or suffix) parameters or member variables with somethings. But why invent a new prefix if there is already one - `this.`?

Answer (score 0):

Use it or don't, just be consistent throughout the codebase. You have to use it if the variable is masked though (by an argument or a local method variable)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your workplace or project has a style guide the specifically prohibits using `this` in this manner, I'd say what you're doing is perfectly fine. I personally use `this` only when it's strictly necessary (e.g., when I'm initializing an instance variable with a method parameter of the same name), but I've seen plenty of code that always uses `this` to reference members. It might be more readable, and it certainly isn't much less readable, so go for it!